# Random Access Machines with only addition, multiplication, equality

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request, computation-models, history

The literature is fairly clear that unit-cost RAMs with primitive multiplication are unreasonable, in that they

1. cannot be simulated by Turing machines in polynomial time
2. can solve PSPACE-complete problems in polynomial time

However, all of the references I can find on this topic (Simon 1974, Schonhage 1979) also involve boolean operations, integer division, etc.

Do there exist any results for the "reasonableness" of RAMs that **only** have addition, multiplication, and equality? In other words, which **do not** have boolean operations, truncated integer division, truncated subtraction, etc?

One would think that such RAMs are still quite "unreasonable." The main red flag is that they enable the generation of exponentially large integers in linear time, and due to the convolution-ish effects of multiplication, this can get particularly complex. However, I cannot actually find any results showing that this allows for any sort of "unreasonable" result (exponential speedup of Turing machine, unreasonable relationship to PSPACE, etc).

Does the literature have any results on this topic?

Comment: Yuval Filmus has a short note summarizing how to solve any problem in NP (and I think any problem in PSPACE?) in polynomial time, using unit-cost RAMs.  Perhaps he'll post a link to that and you can review the methods there to see if they can be generalized to eliminate the need for division.

Comment: Can you think of a way to compute the number $\sum_{i=0}^{2^n-1} 2^{ci}$, where $c$ is a small constant, in your model, using time polynomial in $n,c$?  In other words, we want to compute $(2^{c 2^n}-1)/(2^c-1)$.  This can be done in time polynomial in $n$ and $c$ if we allow division, but can it be done without division?  If it can, I suspect similar results are going to apply to your model as well.

Comment: Do you know where this note is? I've seen literature on unit-cost RAMs being unreasonably powerful when boolean operations are permitted, and truncated division (or shift), with the boolean operations and truncations basically turning the whole thing into a huge parallel device. But, there *should* be some result somewhere showing that even just unit-cost multiplication is "unreasonable" without the other things, because as mentioned, you can quickly compute numbers with more digits than is contained in the observable universe. But, I cannot find a proof of this.

Comment: @D.W. My note shows how to solve all problems in PSPACE in polynomial time. Unfortunately, you need to use bitwise operators (bitwise AND and OR; the two are equivalent). At the time I briefly thought about the very question that you're asking, but came to no conclusion. You can find all of this [here](http://cs.technion.ac.il/~yuvalfi/2017-algebraic-methods/PolySAT.pdf), though it seems you are already aware of it.

Comment: Thanks - did indeed see it. I guess I'm wondering, how could it *not* be the case that there's no speedup with just multiplication? You can keep repeatedly squaring numbers to produce exponentially large, very complex patterns that seem crazy for a Turing machine to produce in polynomial time. Shouldn't there be some kind of growth argument that you can make, since it appears we are using exponential space in linear time (violating $\text{P} \in \text{PSPACE}$)? These problems don't apply for unit-cost addition, just multiplication.

Comment: I once tried a complex "proof" that integer factorization is NP-hard by reduction from subset sum. It didn't work because the integer to factorize was exponentially larger than the input of subset sum. If that would work, would it mean anything related to your question?

Comment: Well, the question is, can you use just addition, multiplication, and equality on exponentially large numbers to solve integer factorization somehow?

Comment: I think that without an operation that collapses states together, that is, a non-injective function like a less-than(-some-constant) test, sign test, truncating division (by some constant) or boolean AND (with some constant), you can never actually *use* the exponential space you develop through multiplication in poly-time: you will always need a (doubly) exponential number of equality tests to finally produce a YES/NO answer.

Comment: Whoops, "non-injective" is not quite right.  What's needed (at the very least) is a function that maps at least 2 elements to some element in the range, and at least 2 other elements to some second element in the range.

Comment: I agree that a RAM requires an exponential amount of space for one thing, but I don't see why you propose a double exponential number of equality tests just to get to ACCEPT/REJECT. Why should it take any longer than *one* equality test? RAMs can do equality testing in unit time, so that last part seems that it should be a non-issue.

Comment: What I mean is that, for a decision problem, we need to somehow collapse a number of states (that is possibly doubly exponential in size) into a single bit. If you have something like a sign test, then with a single application of this test, an unlimited number of input states can produce the output 0, and likewise for the output 1. With only equality testing, each application at best lets you "peel off" 1 input state, implying you need as many applications of the test as you have possible states. (Unless state "compression" can be achieved using just + and \*, but I don't see how.)

Comment: Right now I don't see how you could even *simulate a sign test* in less than (singly) exponential time using just the operations +, \*, =... Am I missing some obvious way?

Comment: I see what you're saying, but the last question has me a bit confused. Let's say there is no way to simulate a sign test with just the operations provided. So then, as you mention, we get no state collapse, and so it's unclear just how useful equality is. But does that really mean that we would really get a *feasible* RAM if we only work with the operations +, *, and =, and throw out things like comparison or sign test? It's the iterated application of * that has me confused.

Comment: Are you saying, "OK, I accept that there are some simple things we can't do with this machine (like seeing if one input number is less than another input number), but are there some crazy things we *can* do (like solve some NP-hard problem, or factor an integer, in poly-time)?"  I'm out of my comfort zone, but I don't think so.  My intuition is that unless you can do "useful" things with a computed numbers -- at a minimum, extract the bits (or decimal digits, etc.) that make it up -- you haven't really "computed" it in any meaningful sense.

Comment: Yes, you interpreted my question correctly, and I see what you're saying. I'm just trying to figure out how far you can take the RAM concept before things get too powerful. It's well-known that when boolean operations are added you do not get a reasonable model of computation, but as you mention, limiting to +, *, = together may not be quite so bad. It would be nice if there were some examples of functions collapsing states other than sign/comparison/truncated arithmetic operations, though. I don't know if just having two different sets of two states that collapse to one is that bad.

Comment: For a book mentioning **[unit-cost RAM](https://books.google.ca/books?id=HFn1BwAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=%22unit-cost+RAMs%22+with+primitive+multiplication&source=bl&ots=GSOqL4NKk7&sig=IKYNKk9upXgX71lwhCpWzYLDv5M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie6tOdg9bbAhWjMX0KHe5BBnwQ6AEIEDAC#v=onepage&q=%22unit-cost%20RAMs%22%20with%20primitive%20multiplication&f=false)** see **The Design and Analysis of Algorithms**, for a question about **Processor in Memory** see [our Monero site](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4487/how-can-i-mine-monero-using-a-processor-in-memory-pcie-card).

Answer (score 2):

The other day I was reading a paper on parallelized random access machines without bit operations, which sounded very much like what you are describing. For these models NC is known not to equal P. See here: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/S0097539794282930

The paper can also be found on Professor Mulmuley’s website.